# How do I choose a certain piece of content in a block of json

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I want to choose size 10 from this link: https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear/products/nkcw7297-100.json ///// The variant is 19437838794880 but I want to be able to select that variant, by making my input '10'///// Here is what I have so far, all this does is get the list of variants

```
function getProd() {
  timeout(delay)
  fetch(urlProd + '.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    var variantsIds = data.product.variants.map(p => p.id);

    var randSize = variantsIds[Math.floor(Math.random()*variantsIds.length)];
    variant = randSize;

    console.log(variant);
  });
}
```

Comment: ? there is no size element in variants...

Comment: check the JSON objects in the link

Comment: the only 'size' string are in tag element  like `productsize-7` there is  no size element

Comment: I want to choose size 10, in the string it is labeled as "title": "10"

Comment: there is no interrest of `getProd()` function, `timeout(delay)` call, and `fetch(..` in your question. read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do

```
let elmWithTitleSize10 =  data.product.variants.find(x=>x.title==='10')

console.log( elmWithTitleSize10 )

// or 
if ( elmWithTitleSize10 ) {
  console.log( 'title', elmWithTitleSize10.title )
}
else {
  console.log( 'not found => title : "10"' )
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: that worked! but it printed the whole JSON item, I want just "title", "10"

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani  I added new line in my answer...